# .ignore extension in PyCharm doesn't work well

Tags: git, pycharm, gitignore, jetbrains-ide

In PyCharm Professional 2023.2 I can't see the "Add to .gitignore"
button, I see only "Add to .gitignore (unignore)".

I reinstalled plugin, restarted IDE and checked Menus and Toolbars section in settings.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that button supposed to have the same functionality?